# Python: Finding the value of a position in a dataframe in Pandas, knowing the value in one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe in python:

```
              Date    Open    High     Low   Close     Volume  Market Cap  \
0     Nov 21, 2017  136.10  142.21  131.37  141.74   72701500  2093010000   
1     Nov 20, 2017  129.50  140.55  128.49  135.76   59945400  1990900000   
2     Nov 19, 2017  130.72  133.62  127.21  129.48   42133000  2009180000   
3     Nov 18, 2017  126.59  135.01  123.53  130.80   62156400  1945200000   
4     Nov 17, 2017  120.02  126.70  119.25  126.70   47127700  1843600000   
5     Nov 16, 2017  121.24  128.09  118.50  120.31   74944100  1861940000   
6     Nov 15, 2017  122.24  124.72  119.19  121.37   49976700  1876740000   
7     Nov 14, 2017  123.62  124.20  118.63  122.35   53544800  1896990000   
8     Nov 13, 2017  128.96  136.53  120.92  123.40  116200000  1978840000   
9     Nov 12, 2017  119.60  133.68  110.62  123.86  144948000  1834630000   
10    Nov 11, 2017  105.75  127.11  103.88  119.62  107708000  1621800000
```

This is stored as test.history. I need to get the value of the column `Close` for the date `20 of November 2017`. How do I do it?

I tried:

```
print testcoin.history.loc['Date'=='Nov 20, 2017','Close']
```

and

```
print testcoin.history.loc('Nov 20, 2017','Close')
```

and many other possibility but I obviously do not understand dataframes well.

P.S. I tried searching for this answer here and looking for the answer online and in tutorials but I always seem to be missing some basic elements to make it work.

Comment: `'Date'=='Nov 20, 2107'` will always evaluate to false since those are indeed different strings. You want e.g., `df.loc[df[<column>] == value, <list of columns>]`

Comment: What is the output of testcoin.info()?  What dtype is Date?

Comment: Thanks @ScottBoston, corrected.

Comment: @ScottBoston, you mean testcoin.history.info() ? 

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1280 entries, 0 to 1279
Data columns (total 9 columns):
Date             1280 non-null object
Open             1280 non-null float64
High             1280 non-null float64
Low              1280 non-null float64
Close            1280 non-null float64
Volume           1280 non-null int64
Market Cap       1280 non-null int64
Coin             1280 non-null object
download_date    1280 non-null object
dtypes: float64(4), int64(2), object(3)
memory usage: 100.0+ KB

Comment: Thanks for all: At the end: 
print float (testcoin.history.loc[testcoin.history['Date']=='Nov 20, 2017','Close'])
made it.

Comment: What does `sum(testcoin.history['Date']=='Nov 20, 2107')' return?

Comment: @Accumulation it returns 0. And if you use 2017 it returns 1. Why?

Comment: What pandas version?

Comment: I have no idea. How do I find out?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
df.loc[df['Date'] == 'Nov 20, 2017', 'Close']
```

if your data frame is called tescoin.history replace that name by df in the code